# Silver light is not getting loaded in Chrome version 40 and above

Tags: google-chrome, npapi

As of now all the chrome browsers version above 40 are coming with disabled NPAPI plugin and it's going to permanently block the support for it. I have a silver light control in my application and am going to to rewrite the functionality with others but temporarily I want this NPAPI plug in to be auto enabled when web application launches in client machine. Is there any way so that I can auto enable NPAPI plug in in chrome through java-script or jquery or is there any other way I can load silver light controls in Chrome browsers without manually enabling it? TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  That would kinda defeat the whole purpose of what they are trying to do.

The closest you could come would be to manually edit the Local Setting json file in the Chrome profile to add the enable-npapi flag, but that would require an executable or installer running on the client machine which would only work if Chrome wasn't running.

The Chrome team has obviously determined that nobody actually has a good reason for using NPAPI, or at least that those reasons aren't good enough, and therefore any of us who rely on it are now required to find another way.

(Frustrated? Me? What ever gave you that idea? ;-))